# Why won't Honda duplicate my key?

Tags: honda, smartkey

One of my 2013 Honda Fit keys broke in half so I went to the local dealer to get a new one.  They told me I had to bring in all the keys to be reprogrammed because if they programmed just one new key the other originals would no longer work (I guess because they reprogram the car too).  I left, but saw a WE DUPLICATE AUTO CHIP KEYS sign at a local home improvement store, and they duplicated the key.  A family member reports her original key continues to work.

Why won't Honda simply duplicate my key?

Comment: Evidently you talked to an idiot or they just were trying to up sell you to spend more money.

Comment: It could be that the immobilizers require pairing all the keys in the process and can't just add new one.

Comment: What part of the key broke? The metal shank? Or the plastic fob?

Comment: @peet: The metal shank came out of the plastic and would not stay back in.  I think a relative might have used the key to pry something and ruined the key.  As I was waiting for the duplicate, another customer said he had multiple Honda keys that also separated.

Comment: @Chebhou: I don't understand the comment.  The home store was willing to duplicate the broken key and thereby let me add a new key with the same coding, but Honda wouldn't do that.

Comment: I meant they are not willing to duplicate the key (could be security reasons )  instead they get new key with new ID and pair it to the car and in the process they redo all old keys.